# Find a .NET object nearest to the given address on the heap (.NET2.0/3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, sos

I would like to locate a .NET object nearest to a specific address on the heap.

#### Example situation

Imagine that from some source I got an address `0x00000000ffaaa690`. When I try to dump an object (using SOS `!do` command) I receive:

`0:000> !do 00000000ffaaa690

<Note: this object has an invalid CLASS field>
Invalid object`

Apparently this address does not point to a valid MT. But I know it's on the .NET heap. How can I locate the nearest MT address (the beginning of the object instance address)?

In the example case the searched object would be at address `00000000ffaaa680`:

`0:000> !do 00000000ffaaa680
Name: System.String
MethodTable: 000007fee6a47d90
EEClass: 000007fee664e560
Size: 36(0x24) bytes
 (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
String: 16457
Fields:
MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fee6a4f000  4000096        8         System.Int32  1 instance                6 m_arrayLength
000007fee6a4f000  4000097        c         System.Int32  1 instance                5 m_stringLength
000007fee6a497d8  4000098       10          System.Char  1 instance               31 m_firstChar
000007fee6a47d90  4000099       20        System.String  0   shared           static Empty
000007fee6a49688  400009a       28        System.Char[]  0   shared           static WhitespaceChars`

**Update 1:**

As Oguz pointed in the comment, there is the lno command in SOS, but I see that it was probably introduced in .NET4.0. My dump is from **.NET2.0/3.5** and it seems that this command is missing :(

Comment: Can lno help?
[ListNearObj (lno) <obj_address>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx)
 
Displays the objects preceding and following the specified address. The command looks for the address in the garbage collection heap that looks like a valid beginning of a managed object (based on a valid method table) and the object following the argument address.

Comment: Thanks @OguzOzgul - I remembered that something like this existed and when I didn't find it in SOS I wrote this question. Now I see that this was probably introduced in .NET4.0 and I have a dump for .NET2.0 :/ I am updating the question.

Comment: Try !sosex.mln.  if your address lands inside an object, method, or any kind of .Net data structure, it will tell you what it is.

Comment: @SteveJohnson I ran !mln against an address on the managed heap a few days ago and the command was still running after 20 minutes. I had to restart Windbg.

Comment: @user2460798 That is highly unusual.  How large is the dump?  Would you be able to share it with me?

Comment: @SteveJohnson it wasn't a dump. I was live debugging. I created a dynamic assembly using Powershell and was stepping through some of the CIL code, and wanted to know what a particular pointer was. Don't know if I can repro, and not sure how I would "give" the repro to you even if I did. One thing you could do is periodically look for Ctrl-Break while executing potentially long running commands.

Comment: @SteveJohnson I was able to reproduce this. I got a FieldInfo from a type I created with Reflection.Emit. I then accessed the private field m_fieldHandle. I entered the value of that pointer as the arg to !mln. I let Windbg run for 20 minutes w no response. It may be the pointer was unmanaged, but it seems like !mln is not as useful if it can't report that it  's argument was to unmanaged memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try !sosex.mln.  It will show you the type of object the address lies in.  It can also tell you if the address is in a managed method or other type of managed data structure.